# SwiftyJSON to rest api - returns nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, swifty-json

SwiftyJSON to rest api - returns nil 
this is my first REST Api experience

```
func getGif(){

        let path = "http://yesno.wtf/api"
        let url = NSURL(string: path)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!){(data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            //print(">>> \(data)")
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            let gif = json["answer"]["forced"]["image"].string
            print("gif: \(gif)")


        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

i use http://yesno.wtf/api

Comment: `let gif = json["image"].string`?

Comment: I think @Larme answer your question, you're trying to access to an key in the dict in the wrong way

Comment: let gif = json["image"].string
print("gif: \(gif!)") thank u  guys, i figured out

Comment: I really like yesno.wtf!